# How to find the most concise sub array of ascending numbers

Tags: arrays, performance, big-o

**In summary:** I need help finding an efficient way to find the shortest or most concise subarray that has the most ascending numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3...) while allowing for random numbers in between.

**Long form:** I am getting "numbers" in a somewhat random order, but I need to find the longest stretch of ascending numbers, but also important is that they take the smallest space possible.  So I need the most concise subarray of the longest run of ascending numbers.  There can be other, spurious numbers in between that get ignored.  For example [1, 2, 1, 3] is a valid 1-3 run and is more concise than the also valid [1, 2, 1, 1, 3].  And a longer run should be more important if possible (e.g. 1-4 wins over 1-3) even if the subarray is significantly longer.

The output will be the indexes of the subarray.  The run will always start with `1` for our purposes, and the result could be an empty array if `1` is not present.  I will always know what the min (1) and max values can be beforehand, but will not know if all those numbers will be present in the input array.

#### Examples

> Input Array: [4, 3, 2, **1**, 1]
>
> Expected Output: [3:4] (zero-base)
>
> Notes: Numbers have to be in ascending order, and the run must start with 1, so the first instance of `1` is the only thing in the returned sub-array.

> Input Array: [4, 1, 2, 3, 1, **1**, 3, **2**, **3**, 1, **4**, 1, 2]
>
> Expected Output: [5:10]
>
> Notes: There are multiple 1-4 runs (i.e. [1:10], [4:10], [5:10]), but shortest one wins.

> Input Array: [**1**, **2**, 2, **3**, 3, **4**, 1, 2, 3]
>
> Expected Output: [0:5]
>
> Notes: Even though the last 3 numbers are a more concise sub-array, the longer run dominates.  Also, last 4 are not it ascending order.

I've tried thinking of sliding windows, but those seem to work better when order is not important, but in my case, I need to know that I've got the shortest ascending group of the longest run.  So that means I need to know what the longest ascending run is first (probably?) and then what the shortest variation of that is.

I'm a little lost on how to handle this simply and effectively. Is there an efficient way to do this, or is it just going to be O(n^2) all the way?

Also if there is a better stack exchange for this question, please let me know.

**Thanks!**

Comment: "while allowing for random numbers in between."  <-- that means the numbers aren't necessarily _consecutive_. Please clarify.

Comment: "most concise subarray" - please define "concise". To my knowledge, "concise" is not a strictly-defined term used in computer-science.

Comment: @Dai, think ["parsimonious"](https://medium.com/@ruhi3929/principle-of-parsimony-d510356ca06a) as a synonym for "concise". I mean consecutive on the number line, but not necessarily consecutive within the array.

Comment: I would go with a variation of Longest Increasing Subsequence problem. There is a well-known `O(nlogn)` algorithm for it (see e.g. here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/), hopefully it could be twisted a bit to detect the shortest ascending group of the longest run.